En java, ¿cómo funciona cuando la clase hijo tiene un atributo que se llama igual que un atributo de la clase padre?
En java tengo una clase padre con un int num1 y por hacer pruebas le he puesto a un int de la clase hijo el mismo nombre num1, y no se contradicen y no salta error. ¿Cómo funcionan estos atributos si se supone que la instancia que cree de la clase hijo solo va a tener un atributo num1? ¿Cuál de los dos atributos va a coger cuando lo inicialize? ¿Qué atributo van a coger los metodos que usen alguno de estos dos atributos?
public class Hijo extends Padre {
    int num3, num4, num1;

    public Hijo(int n, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        super(n , n2);
        num3 = n3;
        num4 = n4;
        num1 = n5;
    }
}


public class Padre {
    int num1, num2;

    public Padre(int n1, int n2) {
        num1 = n1;
        num2 = n2;
    }
}


Creo que he consegido averiguar que es lo que sucede:
Cunado una clase hijo y una clase padre tienen ambos atributos con los mismos identificadores solo se podra acceder a el atributo con el  mismo identificador de la clase padre con el super y el atributo con el mismo identificador de la clase hijo es el que se coje por defecto, entonces por lo general siempre se cogera el atributo hijo aunque se podria seleccionar el padre tambien mediante super o modificadores de acceso

Efectivamente, si ambas clases comparten un método (por ejemplo muy común con el toString() cuando lo invocas desde la clase hija invocas siempre al propio. Para acceder a atributos y/o métodos de la clase padre que existen en la hija se hace a través del super :)

Esto no tiene sentido. ¿Por qué declarar en el hijo un atributo que pertenece al padre? ¡Decláralo en el padre y se lo pasas con super desde el constructor del hijo! En otras palabras, declarar num1 en el hijo es un sin sentido, porque esa propiedad pertenece al padre. ¿Qué es una propiedad del hijo, no del padre? Pues esa propiedad debe llamarse num5, siguiendo tu lógica de nombrado, no num1. De hecho, ayuda más nombrar las propiedades conforme a la realidad, en vez de usar incrementadores.

Si nos vamos a la realidad, imaginemos una clase Persona con una propiedad nombre y una clase Empleado que extiende de Persona. ¿Acaso tiene sentido declarar en Empleado la propiedad nombre cuando esa propiedad pertenece a Persona? Es un despropósito así lo que estás intentando en tu ejemplo. Además, si declaras a nombre con el modificador de acceso protected podrás acceder a esa propiedad desde Empleado. Revisa esta respuesta para más detalles.

@A.Cedano yo entendi que no era su idea repetirlo, si no que probando cosas lo repitio y se quedo con la duda de que pasaba en ese caso... tenes razon en todo.. pero me parece que su pregunta venia por otro lado...

Esto se llama Shadowing, y es una sobreescritura de una variable sobre otra (es como si le hiciera sombra, de ahí el nombre)

Cuando sobrescribes una variable es Shadowing
Cuando sobrescribes un método es override

Para el primer caso, tal como señalaste en tu comentario, la clase hija tendrá acceso a la variable de la clase padre utilizando super


public class Padre {
    String nombre = "Padre";
}

public class Hijo extends Padre{
    String nombre = "Hijo";

    public Hijo() {
        System.out.println(this.nombre);
        System.out.println(super.nombre);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Hijo h = new Hijo();
  // se imprime:
  //Padre
  //Hijo
}



La diferencia entre ambos es que los métodos con override son polimórficos, en cambio las variables con Shadowing no lo son
Analicemos el siguiente ejemplo:
public class Padre {
    String nombre = "Padre";
    
    public  void print() {
        System.out.println(nombre);
    }
}
public class Hijo extends Padre{
    String nombre = "Hijo";
    
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(nombre);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hijo hijo = new Hijo();
    System.out.println(hijo .nombre); // Imprime: Hijo
    hijo .print();   // Imprime: Hijo
    
    Padre padre = new Padre();   // Imprime: Padre
    System.out.println(padre .nombre);  // Imprime: Padre
    padre.print();

    Padre cast = (Padre)hijo;  
    System.out.println(cast.nombre);  // Imprime: Padre
    cast.print();   // Imprime: Hijo
}

Creamos un hijo y padre e imprimimos la variable nombre de 2 formas distintas:

Directamente desde la variable
Utilizando un método que imprime

Como es de esperar el hijo siempre imprime "Hijo" y el padre imprime "Padre".
La diferencia aparece en el tercer caso, cuando casteamos un hijo a padre. Cuando llamamos directamente a la variable nombre accede a la variable de la clase Padre, en cambio al llamar al método, respeta el polimorfismo y llama al método de la clase Hijo, porque el objeto aunque esté casteado en el fondo sigue siendo Hijo
